# Bootstrap: Unwanted accordion behaviour

Tags: bootstrap-4

The following code works fine....except....
I don't want to expand or callapse a row when the user clicks a checkbox. How can I block this?
(I have jquery plugged in. I'm wondering if I can use this to solve the problem?)

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <td>
            <h5>Select All:</h5>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h5><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"></h5>
        </td>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" , value="Replace Selected"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tgt1">

            <td> Heading </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="92340332" name="c1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="tgt1" class="collapse">content content</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tgt2">
            <td>Heading</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="146735230" name="c2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="tgt2" class="collapse">content content</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `e.stopPropagation();` to your `checkbox` to prevent.

```
 $("myElement").on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); })
```

or

```
$('input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevents event e from going to parent
});
```

Comment: given I have up to 100 dynamically named checkboxes, I assume the second solution will suit me better?

Comment: @Jake yes you can also give class to your checkbox.